# Extend Django Admin UserCreationForm with OneToOneField

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-admin

I'm trying to extend the django admin UserCreationForm to include a field from another table related on a OneToOneField.

This is my related table:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='supervisor',
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        blank = True,
        null = True
    )
```

And my admin form:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class EmailRequiredMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmailRequiredMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # make user email field required
        self.fields['email'].required = True


class MyUserCreationForm(EmailRequiredMixin, UserCreationForm):
    supervisor = forms.Select()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username',]

    def save(self, commit=True):
        if not commit:
            raise NotImplementedError("Can't create User and UserProfile without database save")
        user = super(MyUserCreationForm, self).save(commit=True)
        profile = Profile(user=user, supervisor=self.cleaned_data['supervisor'])
        profile.save()
        return user, profile

class EmailRequiredUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [ProfileInline, ]
    list_display = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'get_supervisor', 'get_is_supervisor', 'get_is_project_manager']
    form = MyUserChangeForm
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm
    add_fieldsets = ((None, {'fields': ('username', 'email',
                                        'password1', 'password2'), 'classes': ('wide',)}),)

    def get_supervisor(self, instance):
        return instance.profile.supervisor
    get_supervisor.short_description = 'Supervisor'

    def get_is_supervisor(self, instance):
        return instance.profile.is_supervisor()
    get_is_supervisor.short_description = 'Is Supervisor'

    def get_is_project_manager(self, instance):
        return instance.profile.is_project_manager()
    get_is_project_manager.short_description = 'Is Project Manager'

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return list()
        return super(EmailRequiredUserAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, EmailRequiredUserAdmin)
```

Within django-admin it just shows the normal creation form but I need to include the supervisor.  I know I haven't included the queryset for the supervisor at this stage, but I think this explains what I'm trying to achieve and what I've attempted.

Would appreciate help.

Comment: Why not have two forms?

Comment: How do I do that within django-admin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to add supervisor field to your admin add_fieldsets.

```
class MyTestForm(UserCreationForm):
    supervisor = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        supervisor = self.cleaned_data['supervisor']
        # Save user first 
        user = super(MyTestForm, self).save(commit=True)
        profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user)
        profile.supervisor = supervisor
        profile.save()
        return user


class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = MyTestForm
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('supervisor', 'username', 'password1', 'password2')
        }),
    )
```

I tested this solution and supervisor shows up as dropdown in the create step.
Hope it helps.

Comment: That gives me `Unknown field(s) (supervisor) specified for User. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class EmailRequiredUserAdmin.` because supervisor is in the `Profile` model

Comment: I probably misunderstood.. you want to show the ProfileInline in the creation step?

Comment: Sort of.  I want to show 1 field (called `supervisor`) from `Profile` which is a table with a 121 relationship with `User`.  I want this single field added to the creation step.

Comment: I updated with a more verbose solution, hope it helps.

Comment: This does show the user in the drop down.  But it is not saving it to the Profile.  I've added my code where I do something with `supervisor` - perhaps you can help

Comment: I modified it slightly. The user must first be saved or the create will fail for the Profile.objects.create(user=user) (The user does not yet exist in database)

Comment: I must have failed to comied that line of code in because I am doing that but it is not being saved into the `Profile` model

Comment: Got it - the issue was I had a signal on `post_save` for the `user` which created a `Profile` object for the `user`.  Things were getting confused.